# how to call C methods with Char** argument and int* arguments from python?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

This is the `module.py script` which loads the `erf_utils_io_D.dll` which contains `io.c` and `io.h` files
I am successful in loading the library and passing the ctype arguments like

> c_int, c_float, POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_Float)

**module.py**

```
//python code module.py
    import sys
    from ctypes import *
    #load the required library and make sure the folder where    erf_utils_io_D.dll is present

dll = CDLL('D:\\erf_utils_python\\erf_utils_io.dll')
getContourResults = dll.getContourResults

class Utility(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('i am inside init')
        self.stagename = "post"
        self.stateids = (c_int * 1) (2934)
        self.stateidcount = 1
        self.entityidcount = 1
        self.entityid = (c_int * 1) (1)
        self.entitytype = "FPM"
        self.variablecount = 1
        self.ores = [1.0]
        self.filename ='allinone_RESULT.erfh5'
        #This is how char** is treted in python for variablegroup
        self.variablegroup = ["FPM_Mach_Number"]
        self.string_length = len(self.variablegroup)
        self.select_type = (c_wchar_p * self.string_length)
        self.select = self.select_type()
        for key, item in enumerate(self.variablegroup):
                 self.select[key] = item


        #This is how char** is treated infor variable
        self.variable = ["FPM_Mach_Number"]
        self.var_len = len(self.variable)
        self.var_type = (c_wchar_p * self.var_len)
        self.variable_list = self.var_type()
        for key, item in enumerate(self.variable):
              self.variable_list[key] = item


    def run(self):
        getContourResults.argtypes = (POINTER(c_char_p), POINTER(c_char_p), c_int, POINTER(c_int),
                              c_int, POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_char), c_int, self.select_type ,
                              self.var_type, POINTER(c_float))

        getContourResults.restype = (c_int)


        err = getContourResults(self.filename, self.stagename, self.stateidcount,
        self.stateids, self.entityidcount,self.entityid, self.entitytype, self.variablecount, self.select, self.variable_list, self.ores)


reader = Utility()
reader.run()
```

**code.cpp looks like this**

```
extern "C"
{
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) int getContourResults(char* iFilename, char* iStagename, int iStateidCnt, int* Stateids,
        int iEntityIdCount, int* iEntityids, char* iEntityType,
        int iVariablecnt, char** iVariablegroup, char** ivariable,
        float* oResults);
}
```

Please let me know how to pass arguments from ***python script to the method*** `getContourResults()` present in io.c

Comment: _Typically_, a `char**` is expected to point to the beginning of a NUL-terminated array of `char*`s; have you determined whether that's actually the case here?

Comment: BTW, it's going to be hard to test answers to this, as people who aren't you won't have `erf_utils_io.dll`. It's typically a route to better results to find a comparable calling convention among standard-library utilities and build a [mre] around it, so folks answering your question will be able to actually test their answers (and people judging and voting on those answers, likewise).

Comment: Python cannot call such a function directly.  You will need to create a wrapper function that exposes an interface consistent with [Python's C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) to adapt your target function.  You could write such a wrapper in C, directly to the C API, or you should also be able to write it in [Cython](https://cython.org/), which has a much more Python-like feel.

Comment: The first two parameters are to `getContourResults` are `c_char_p,c_char_p` not `POINTER(c_char_p),POINTER(c_char_p)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no indication of implementation of the function so I made one with some assumptions.  You should be able to adapt to your real use case with this example.  Main fixes were `.argtypes` corrections and using `c_char_p` instead of `c_wchar_p` and a simple helper function for turning a list into a ctypes array.

Here's some clarification on types:

- `c_char_p` == `char*` in C.  Pass a byte string, e.g. `b'string'`.
- `c_wchar_p` == `wchar_t*` in C.  Pass a Unicode string, e.g. `'string'`.
- `POINTER(c_char_p)` == `char**` in C.
- `POINTER(c_float)` == `float*` in C.  Create storage (`c_float()`) and pass `byref`.  Access the returned float as a Python integer with `.value` member.

**test.cpp**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int getContourResults(char* iFilename, char* iStagename, int iStateidCnt, int* Stateids,
    int iEntityIdCount, int* iEntityids, char* iEntityType,
    int iVariablecnt, char** iVariablegroup, char** ivariable,
    float* oResults)
{
    printf("iFilename = %s\n"
           "iStagename = %s\n"
           ,iFilename,iStagename);
    for(int i = 0; i < iStateidCnt; ++i)
        printf("Stateids[%d] = %d\n",i,Stateids[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < iEntityIdCount; ++i)
        printf("iEntityids[%d] = %d\n",i,iEntityids[i]);
    printf("iEntityType = %s\n",iEntityType);
    for(int i = 0; i < iVariablecnt; ++i) {
        printf("iVariablegroup[%d] = %s\n",i,iVariablegroup[i]);
        printf("ivariable[%d] = %s\n",i,ivariable[i]);
    }
    *oResults = 1.2f;
    return 5;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.getContourResults = dll.getContourResults
dll.getContourResults.argtypes = (c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int,POINTER(c_int),c_int,POINTER(c_int),c_char_p,
                              c_int,POINTER(c_char_p),POINTER(c_char_p),POINTER(c_float))
dll.getContourResults.restype = c_int

def make_array(ctype,arr):
    return len(arr),(ctype * len(arr))(*arr)

def getContourResults(filename,stagename,sids,eids,entitytype,groups,variables):
    stateidcount,stateids = make_array(c_int,sids)
    entityidcount,entityid = make_array(c_int,eids)
    groups = [b'group1',b'group2']
    variables = [b'var1',b'var2']
    if len(groups) != len(variables):
        raise ValueError('assuming groups and variables same length')
    _,variablegroup = make_array(c_char_p,groups)
    variablecount,variable = make_array(c_char_p,variables)
    ores = c_float()
    err = dll.getContourResults(filename,stagename,stateidcount,stateids,entityidcount,entityid,
                                entitytype,variablecount,variablegroup,variable,byref(ores))
    return err,ores.value

sids = [1,2,3]
eids = [4,5,6]
groups = [b'group1',b'group2']
variables = [b'var1',b'var2']
err,ores = getContourResults(b'filename',b'stagename',sids,eids,b'entitytype',groups,variables)
print(f'err = {err}')
print(f'ores = {ores:.2f}')
```

**Output:**

```
iFilename = filename
iStagename = stagename
Stateids[0] = 1
Stateids[1] = 2
Stateids[2] = 3
iEntityids[0] = 4
iEntityids[1] = 5
iEntityids[2] = 6
iEntityType = entitytype
iVariablegroup[0] = group1
ivariable[0] = var1
iVariablegroup[1] = group2
ivariable[1] = var2
err = 5
ores = 1.20
```

Comment: what if when we need to output char **values from a method, how do we declare in script in argtypes and how do we return

Comment: @sandhya Ask a new question with a [mcve].  If this answer answered this question, consider upvoting/accepting it.  See [What to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: `int GetNames(char* iFilename, char** oNames)
{
 int oNumNames, oStatus;
 /*io* pIo = GetIoInstance();*/
 std::vector<EString> names;
 CreateIoInstance(iFilename);
 oStatus = pIo->get_names(names);
 oNumNames = (int)names.size();

 for (int ii = 0; ii < oNumNames; ii++)
 {
  strcpy(oNames[ii], names[ii].c_str());
 }
 return 0;
}` this the code in C layer I need to call this method from python layer and I am worried with second argument how to allocate memory for onames

Comment: @sandhya I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139780/235698) in your other question.

Comment: Here in the above example it outputs err and ores.value and it prints 1.20 in output, so my question is if  *oresults = {1.20, 1.30, 1.50} then how can we allocate memory for this float array and how to print this on output.(And also we don't know the size of ores in python to allocate memory)

Comment: @sandhya Then you allow are the memory inside the c code and provide a freeing function as in the other answer I linked.

Comment: I don't know the size inside the C code, C code calls C++ methods which fills the array *oresults..so how can we do this ,please do explain with a example..generally I need to know how to allocate memory in python script for float arrays, int arrays which need to be passed to C merthod.

Comment: @sandhya Ask a new question and give a concrete example (like in my answers) of how C code populates array. You need to know the size somehow.

Comment: raised a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64312490/how-to-pass-float-array-to-c-method-from-python-script-whose-memory-allocation